# Do a random position for a sprite in cocos 2D

Tags: xcode, random, cocos2d-iphone, position, sprite

Hi every one well I'm on cocos2D and here is my code:

```
target.position = ccp(actualX, 0);
```

But I would like to add a random position like:

```
arc4random() / (UINT_MAX/2);

switch(position) {
    case 0: /* top */
         target.position = ccp(actualX, 200);
        break;;

    case 1: /* bottom */
         target.position = ccp(actualX, 100);
        break;
```

How can I do it please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get a random number between 0 and 3, and then apply your cases to each one of the cases, like below:

```
int positionCase = arc4random() % 4;

switch(positionCase) 
{
    case 0:
         target.position = ccp(actualX, 0);
        break;

    case 1:
        target.position = ccp(actualX, 200); 
        break;

    case 2:
         target.position = ccp(0, actualY); 
        break;

    case 3:
         target.position = ccp(200, actualY);
        break;
}
```

Comment: target.position = ccp(200, actualY);

Comment: target.position = ccp(100, actualY);

Comment: What exactly is the question then?  Maybe I misunderstood.  You can use arc4random() % SOME_MAX_VALUE to generate any random number between 0 and SOME_MAX_VALUE.  What exactly is the logic you are looking for?  Should x or y or both be random?  Or do you want one of your switch cases to be random?

Comment: one of your switch cases to be random?

Comment: Meaning do you want position to equal some random number?  Like position = arc4random() % MAX_SWITCH_CASES

Comment: no random between four things : target.position = ccp(actualX, 0);                  target.position = ccp(actualX, 200);      target.position = ccp(0, actualY); and   target.position = ccp(200, actualY);

Comment: I made mistakes in my question sorry :/

Answer (score 4):

I think its easy.. If You are using a landscape mode for iPhone...(480x320)

```
int positionX = arc4random()%480;
int positionY = arc4random()%320;
[sprite setPosition:ccp(positionX,positionY)];
```

This will add your sprite anywhere on the screen. Change resolution according to screen.